# Laravel ajax map all inputs

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have multi step form with different data type such as `multiple checkbox, radio button and input (text)` as my form steps are dynamic (depend on data from database) i cannot provide static data to send in backend like `data: {1: one, 2:two, etc.}`  I need the way to make this `data:{}` dynamic, i mean if i have 5 inputs in my form send 5 data to backend, if i have 12 inputs then send 12 data.

## Code

```
success:function(data){ // getting my form inputs from backend
    $('.projectName').append('of ', data.project.name);

    //return existed data to quizzes
    var index = 0;
    var countdownTimer = null;
    var count = 0;
    $("#clicks").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // timer function
        function timer(seconds, countdownTimer, callback) {
            var days = Math.floor(seconds / 24 / 60 / 60);
            var hoursLeft = Math.floor((seconds) - (days * 86400));
            var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
            var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600));
            var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
            var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
            if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
            }
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
            if (seconds == 0) {
                clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Times Up!";
                $("#clicks").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#clicks").hide();
                $('.answerPanel').html('<div class="text-center text-danger">OH NO! <br> Times Up!</div>');
            } else {
                seconds--;
            }
            //Pass seconds param back to the caller.
            callback(seconds);
        }
        //We pass the countdownTimer param into the timer function as well.
        if (countdownTimer != null) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        }
        if(typeof data.quizzes[index] !== 'undefined'){
            seconds = data.quizzes[index].quiz_time;
        }
        countdownTimer = setInterval(function() {
            timer(seconds, countdownTimer, function(_seconds){
                seconds = _seconds;
            })
        }, 1000);



        // printing function (this is my form inputs "3 types")
        if(typeof data.quizzes[index] !== 'undefined'){
            var html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="pull-left questionTitle">'+data.quizzes[index].question+'</div><div class="pull-right" id="countdown"></div></div></div>';
            if(data.quizzes[index].choices.length > 0){
                html+='<div class="col-md-12">';
                if(data.quizzes[index].question_type == 'multiple'){
                    data.quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                        html+='<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">';
                        html+='<input id="choice" name="choice" type="checkbox" value="'+element.choice+'">';
                        html+='<label for="checkbox2">'+element.choice+'</label>';
                        html+='</div>';
                    });
                } else if (data.quizzes[index].question_type == 'single') {
                    data.quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                        html+='<div class="radio radio-primary">';
                        html+='<input id="choice" name="choice" type="radio" value="'+element.choice+'">';
                        html+='<label>'+element.choice+'</label>';
                        html+='</div>';
                    });
                } else {
                    data.quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                        html+='<div class="radio radio-primary">';
                        html+='<input id="choice" name="choice" type="text" value="'+element.choice+'">';
                        html+='<label>'+element.choice+'</label>';
                        html+='</div>';
                    });
                }
                html+='</div>';
            }
            $(".answerPanel").html(html);
            index++;
        }

        if(data.quizzes.length > index+1) {
            $("#clicks").html("Next");
        }
        if(data.quizzes.length === index) {
            $("#clicks").html("Send");
            $('#clicks').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success saveAnswers');
        }
        //end of printing function

        //send form data
        $('.saveAnswers').unbind().bind('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            // var formData = new FormData();
            // formData.append('radio buttons', $(this).closest("form").find("input[name=choice]").is(':checked'));
            // formData.append('select options', $(this).closest("form").find("input[name=choice]").is(':selected'));
            // formData.append('text inputs', $(this).closest("form").find("input[name=choice]").is(':selected'));
            $.post({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{route('quizzes.store')}}',
                dataType: "json",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: formData,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
        //send form data
    });
}
```

> Note: I shared full code in case you need to figure out the logic but
>   to be clear my issue is in saving part that i commented with `//send form data`

**PS:** some of my form data are multiple choice (checkbox)

**Example:**

Let say one of my form has 3 steps with 3 different types, here how i need the data,

```
{
"step 1" : {good, bad} // checkbox
"step 2" : {no} // radio button
"step 3": {this is my testing input} // text input
}
```

This data will be saved in `json` column, so it needs to be send as json i guess.

## Question

How can I wrap my dynamic inputs and send data to backend?

## Update

Well as I was losing the data of each step after clicking next button i've decided to save data of each step in localStorage and then send them at once in final step.

with my edited code i am facing 3 issues:

1. Else part won't work
2. Data of second step will save in localStorage when i click in first step! also in different rows instead of their row as json `{}`
   [image: two]
3. Next steps clears previous step data in localStorage.

### code

```
// printing function
if(typeof data.quizzes[index] !== 'undefined'){
    var html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="pull-left questionTitle">'+data.quizzes[index].question+'</div><div class="pull-right" id="countdown"></div></div></div>';
    if(data.quizzes[index].choices.length > 0){
        html+='<div class="col-md-12">';
        if(data.quizzes[index].question_type == 'multiple'){
            data.quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                html+='<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">';
                html+='<input class="styled form-check-input" id="choice" name="'+data.quizzes[index].question+'[]" type="checkbox" value="'+element.choice+'">';
                html+='<label class="control-label">'+element.choice+'</label>';
                html+='</div>';
                // added part
                $('#clicks').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var checkboxes = [];
                    $("input[name='"+data.quizzes[index].question+"']").each(function(){
                        checkboxes.push(this.value);
                    });
                    console.log(checkboxes);
                    localStorage.setItem(data.quizzes[index].question, JSON.stringify(checkboxes));
                });
            });
        } else if (data.quizzes[index].question_type == 'single') {
            data.quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                html+='<div class="radio radio-primary">';
                html+='<input class="styled form-check-input" id="radio" name="'+data.quizzes[index].question+'" type="radio" value="'+element.choice+'">';
                html+='<label class="control-label">'+element.choice+'</label>';
                html+='</div>';
                // added part
                $('#clicks').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var radios = [];
                    $("input[name='"+data.quizzes[index].question+"']").each(function(){
                        radios.push(this.value);
                    });
                    console.log(radios);
                    localStorage.setItem(data.quizzes[index].question, JSON.stringify(radios));
                });
            });
        } else { // added part
            alert('hi');
            data.quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                html+='<div class="row">hi';
                html+='<input id="input" name="'+data.quizzes[index].question+'" type="text">';
                html+='<label>'+element.choice+'</label>';
                html+='</div>';
                // added part
                $('#clicks').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var inputss = [];
                    $("input[name='"+data.quizzes[index].question+"']").each(function(){
                        inputss.push(this.value);
                    });
                    console.log(inputss);
                    localStorage.setItem(data.quizzes[index].question, JSON.stringify(inputss));
                });
            });
        }
        html+='</div>';
    }
    $(".answerPanel").html(html);
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Why not send the data as an array - then you can have as many inputs as you like and you will just handle them as part of the array.

Comment: @James that's what i'm trying to do, getting array of all inputs and send it as json

Comment: If all your inputs are wrap in single form then on the every click on which you are sending data just in your form data append a key value something like {step:"one"} then in your controller check this step and make validations according to this field "Step" I have had this situation, I managed it like this

Comment: and also make sure that there is no required attribute for any input, you have to manage this by yourself

Comment: @BlackXero as I've faced issue of sending data to backend at once i've decided to store data of each step in localStorage and then send them at once, but currently having issue of getting values to localStorage.

Comment: @BlackXero maybe you can help with my update?